# Autoresizing JtextPane after Font Size Change

Tags: java, swing, font-size, word-wrap

I load a text in a `JTextPane` and automatically every line takes the max number of words it can. When I decrease the `Font` size text just zoom out and all lines are half empty. How can I auto resize the text so every line is filled no matter what size of `Font` I use?
The code for changing font is

```
JComboBox cb =(JComboBox)evt.getSource();
String Selection =(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
int n = Integer.parseInt(Selection);
Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, n);
        editPane.setFont(font);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).